# JQuery capturing table row lost focus

Tags: jquery

suppose i have table with 5 columns. in each column any kind of things could be there like only text or text inside span or input box, dropdown, checkbox or radio button etc. i want when user switch focus from any control to other row of same table or out side out that table then a function will be triggered or show alert like focus lost.

i got a similar script but it is not working as expected. here whole code.

```
<div id="grd1">
<table>
    <tr id="tx"><td>Hello1</td><td><input /></td><td><input /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello2</td><td><input /></td><td><input /></td></tr>
</table>
</div>

var delayedFn, blurredFrom;
$('#grd1 table tr').on('blur', ':input', function(event) {
    blurredFrom = event.delegateTarget;
    delayedFn = setTimeout(function() {
        alert('Blurred');
    }, 0);
});
$('#grd1 table tr').on('focus', ':input', function(event) {
//alert(event.delegateTarget);
    if (blurredFrom === event.delegateTarget) {
        clearTimeout(delayedFn);
    }
});
```

jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/dU8sn/96/
please tell me where is the mistake. test this way when click on any text box of first row repeatedly then just click on hello1 text then you will see focus lost occur but it should not be because hello1 is also in first row.

guide me where is the mistake. thanks

### Edit

bit modify the code but still no luck.

```
<div id="grd1">
  <table>
    <tr id="t1">
      <td tabindex="0"><span>Hello1</span></td>
      <td tabindex="1">
        <input />
      </td>
      <td tabindex="2">
        <input />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="t2">
      <td tabindex="3"><span>Hello2</span></td>
      <td tabindex="4">
        <input />
      </td>
      <td tabindex="5">
        <input />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

var delayedFn, blurredFrom;
$('#grd1 table tr').on('blur', 'td, input, th', function(event) {
  alert(blurredFrom);
  alert($(this).closest('tr').attr('id'));
  if (blurredFrom !='undefined' && blurredFrom != $(this).closest('tr').attr('id')) {
        alert('Blurred');
  }
  //blurredFrom = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
  //delayedFn = setTimeout(function() {
    //alert('Blurred');
  //}, 0);
});

$('#grd1 table tr').on('focus', 'td, input, th', function(event) {
blurredFrom === $(this).closest('tr').attr('id')
  //alert(blurredFrom);
  //if (blurredFrom === $(this).closest('tr').attr('id')) {
    //alert('clr')
    //clearTimeout(delayedFn);
  //}
});
```

### EDIT

after spending good time i could build right script what i was looking for.

```
<table id="myTable">
   <tr id="t1">
      <td>
         <span>Hello1</span>
      </td>
      <td>
         <input id="c1r1" type="text" value="c1r1" />
      </td>
      <td>
         <select>
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
         </select>
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car 
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="t2">
      <td>
         Hello2
      </td>
      <td>
         <input id="c1r2" type="text" value="c1r2" />
      </td>
      <td>
         <select>
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
         </select>
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car 
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>

var rowid = '';

$(function () {
    //Click event
$('#myTable tr').on('click',  function(event) {

        if(rowid=='')
    {
        rowid=$(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    }

    if(rowid!='' && rowid!=$(this).closest('tr').attr('id'))
    {
      rowLostFocus();
      rowid=$(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    }
});


$("body").click(function(e) {
        if (e.target.id == "myTable" || $(e.target).parents("#myTable").size()) { 
            //alert("Inside table");
        } else { 
           rowLostFocus();
           alert("Outside table");
        }
    });
});

function rowLostFocus()
{
   alert('Row '+rowid+' lost focus');
}
```

Comment: this is latest working sample of js fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/tridip/7xmybgwx/4/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot focus on `<td>` or `<tr>` as long as they don't have the `tabindex` attribute. So kindly try adding a `tabindex` for all those elements that needs focussing. Also, you need to change the way you are trying to decide if the "row" gets focussed.

```
<div id="grd1">
    <table>
        <tr id="tx"><td tabindex="0">Hello1</td><td><input /></td><td><input /></td></tr>
        <tr><td tabindex="0">Hello2</td><td><input /></td><td><input /></td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

May be the above code will work as expected, as other than the `<input />` I have given the `tabindex` for the `<td>` (first column).

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/on18nsme/**

Comment: not working just see your fiddle. check your code this way....click on 1st textbox of first row and then click on hello1 text of 1st row then you will see lost focus is occurring but lost focus should not occur because hello1 and text box1 is in same row.

Comment: @Thomas Did you do pressing `Tab` key? Instead of clicking on the first text box?

Comment: user can navigate many way. user may press tab or click. click on 1st textbox on first row and then press tab and again press twice shift+tag to place focus on hello1 text then u will notice blur alter is coming.....which is not right.

Comment: @Thomas Guess this deals with the time between the transfer of focus takes place. May be delay your check using a `setTimeout` for `200 ms`?